# Attach color style and design element to Angular reusable component

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-components, reusability

I have reusable component button in Angular application  on `login.component.html` with `login.component.ts` attaching button name with `label` and function `event`:

```
<app-my-btn (onClick)="myFunction($event)" [label]="label"></app-my-btn>
```

with `@Input()` and `@Output()` `this.onClick.emit(event);` in `my-btn.component.ts` with own style in `my-btn.component.scss`.

I'm trying to figure out, how to pass style elements like `color` and `icon` from `login.component.ts` where I'm have specific function and button name.

In result I'm trying to get two buttons with different function, color, icons and names, but the same design from single component `my-btn.component.scss`

Any guide or advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best way is to define certain SCSS classes in your `my-btn-component.scss` and then pass the class name to the component.

**TS**

```
// when an input arrives, the class gets replaced and the HTML immediately updates
@Input() currentClass: string = "default-style";
```

**HTML**

```
<app-my-btn (onClick)="myFunction($event)" [label]="label" [class]="currentClass"></app-my-btn>
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for late replay. Please check my edit, because seems like I'm doing something wrong way with trying to use your code